# vsdbg on MacOS Ventura (intel) seems to be failing

Tags: .net, macos

I've upgraded to MacOS Ventura on Intel and am having trouble getting the debugger to work. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, version 17.4.2 (latest stable).

To Reproduce:

- I create a default macOS Application (Mac -> App -> .Net). This is a Cocoa app using a storyboard, with .Net7.
- Click "Run Project". The app runs fine.
- Click "Start Debugging Project". In the application output tab, I see the licence message "You may only use...", and then nothing. The app doesn't start. There's no more messages.

Looking in console - I can see this message:

> /Users/Paul/Dev/DotNetMacOSTestProject/TestDotNet7/bin/Debug/net7.0-macos/osx-x64/TestDotNet7.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libmscordbi.dylib"
> (cs_mtime:1671400321.653023908 == mtime:1671400321.653023908)
> (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 nx:0 wpmapped:0 dirty:0 depth:0)

Further down there is the following message:

> Aggregated. Transform: StabilityCrashNumerator3 Dirty: 1 Event:
> com.apple.stability.crash
> {"coalitionName":"com.microsoft.visual-studio","exceptionCodes":"0x0000000000000032,
> 0x00000001094f0000(\n    50,\n    4451139584\n)EXC_BAD_ACCESSSIGKILL
> (Code Signature Invalid)UNKNOWN_0x32 at
> 0x00000001094f0000","incidentID":"85F597C2-48CC-4C55-ADEA-77D3E588FAE9","logwritten":0,"process":"vsdbg-ui","responsibleApp":"VisualStudio","terminationReasonExceptionCode":"0x2","terminationReasonNamespace":"**CODESIGNING**","timestamp":1671400809131127}

So... likely CodeSigning.

Switching the project to .Net6 I see the same result - the app runs ok but can't debug.
I have reinstalled visual studio - same result.
I can run vsdbg-ui from the command line, and it starts.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong? Or what sort of troubleshooting I can do.
Thx.
Paul

Comment: Just tested it in 17.5 Preview. Got the same result.

Comment: Plus... reviewing console logs further I see the following invalid page error: "CODE SIGNING: process 85696[vsdbg-ui]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x106ac3000 from offset 0x0 in file "/Users/Paul/Dev/DotNetMacOSTestProject/TestDotNet7/bin/Debug/net7.0-macos13.0/osx-x64/TestDotNet7.app/Contents/MonoBundle/libmscordbi.dylib" (cs_mtime:1671402937.619305157 == mtime:1671402937.619305157) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 nx:0 wpmapped:0 dirty:0 depth:0)"

Comment: which logs are you looking at? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: @NickSpag I'm so glad to hear someone else is having the issue... I thought it had to just be me. I'm using the console app, then filter by "VisualStudio"

Comment: We think its narrowed down to the debugger being prevented from attaching to the process by macOS' security settings. Can you confirm- that you *don't* get the "developer tools access needs to take control of another proess" prompt when you try to debug a new macOS net6/7 app? But you *do* get the prompt with a new iOS net6/7 application?

Comment: If this bash command works for you ill post the full answer later once i have more time to test it, but I think it just worked for me in Jetbrains' Rider. It downloads a script here that redownloads and installs (and repair? not sure havent disected the script) vsdbg. curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
cp ~/vsdbg/libdbgshim.dylib ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2-darwin-x64/.debugger/x86_64/ see the thread here https://mastodon.social/@filipnavara/109503277853737918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that if you're running on Mac vsdbg and vsdbg-ui (the underlying executables that are used for cross-platform debugging of .NET core code) need to be re code-signed with a trusted cert.

Please see [the issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4903) I opened on Github.

There is a temporary workaround which was posted by github user @basilfx which will likely fix your issue.

His answer applied to VS code but you just need to find the executables used in your case and apply the same fix.

I'll restate his answer below for convenience but [here is the link to his comment in the Github issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4903#issuecomment-993015843)

---

Create self-signed code signing certificate:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58363510/1423623
- Navigate to the debugger folder (in my case, ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.24.4-darwin-x64/.debugger/x86_64)
- Run codesign --remove-signature vsdbg-ui && codesign --remove-signature vsdbg
- Run codesign -s my-codesign-cert vsdbg-ui && codesign -s my-codesign-cert vsdbg

---

If you ever update your Visual Studio be careful because it may also replace the vsdbg/vsdbg-ui executables with fresh versions that you have to reapply the fix on because your code signed executables have been replaced.

Long term fix is in Microsoft's court at this point.

EDIT:
Alternative option is to force your Mac to stop enforcing the "allow apps downloaded from App Store and identified developers" restriction.

This is a hidden option in the System Preferences -> Privacy area that used to be visible in Sierra and earlier.

```bash
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Then close any already open System Preferences app and then open System Preferences -> Privacy -> General tab and you should see that there is now an "Anywhere" option under the "Allow apps downloaded from:" area.

This has effectively turned off the need for apps to be signed by developers so do so at your own risk!